# how to name the assumption when remembering an expression?

Tags: coq

The documentation for Coq carries the general admonition *not* to rely on the builtin naming mechanism, but select one's own names, lest the changes in the naming mechanism render past proofs invalid.

When considering expressions of the form `remember Expr as v`, we set the variable `v` to the expression `Expr`. But the name of the assumption is selected automatically, and is something like `Heqv`, so we have:

`Heqv: v = Expr`

How can I select my own name instead of `Heqv`? I can always rename it to whatever I like using the `rename` command, but that doesn't keep my proofs independent of the hypothetical future changes in the builtin naming mechanism in Coq.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you may get rid of the separate equality, try `set (name := val)`.  Use `unfold` instead of `rewrite` to get the value back in place.

If you need the equality for more than the `rewrite <-`, I know of no built in tactic that does this.  You can do it manually, though, or build a tactic / notation.  I just threw this together.  (Note: I'm not an expert, this might be done more easily.)

```
Tactic Notation "remember_as_eq" constr(expr) ident(vname) ident(eqname) :=
  let v     := fresh in
  let HHelp := fresh in
    set (v := expr);
    (assert (HHelp : sigT (fun x => x = v)) by ( apply (existT _ v); reflexivity));
    inversion HHelp as [vname eqname];
    unfold v in *; clear v HHelp;
    rewrite <- eqname in *.
```

Use as `remember_as_eq (2+2) four Heqfour` to get the same result as with `remember (2+2) as four`.

---

Note: Updated to handle more cases, the old version failed on some combinations of value and goal type. Leave a comment if you find another case that works with `rewrite` but not this one.

Comment: Note that you can also define it as `Tactic Notation "remember" constr(expr) "as" ident(vname) "withEq" ident(eqname)` if you prefer using it as `remember (2+2) as four withEq Heqfour`, but this will bork the parser and shadow the builtin `remember _ as _.`.  If you use `Tactic Notation "remember" constr(expr) "with" ident(eqname) "as" ident(vname)` (or `withEq` instead of `with` or ...), the ordering is weird but the old `remember` will still be accessible.